# C Stack usage error while using RSRuby with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r

I try to use RSRuby to execute some R script within my rails project. I created a method inside a module, I call this module from a model and want to store the return value.

When I execute this method (from the model > module) using the rails console everything works fine. But when I try to execute this same method within my rails application I get the following error:

```
Error: C stack usage  17589268476924 is too close to the limit
Error: C stack usage  17589268476972 is too close to the limit
Error: C stack usage  17589268476876 is too close to the limit
Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT
```

This error is not related to the R Script (I tried several very simple scripts, but get the same error regardless of the R code I execute). Does anybody have an idea how I could fix this problem?

Apart from this error I found RSRuby the most suitable way to integrate R within Ruby, I had other problems when trying to use RinRuby (a gem load error when starting the rails server, because R could not be found). Executing code from the CLI seems inefficient and returns the output as a string, which is in this case also not feasible.

Comment: I am not sure but I think it looks like memory error, The size of the stack is close to the default maximum value. I would check if I can increase the stack limit in options.

Comment: It's a weird error though, there should not be a memory issue here, even adding up 1 and 1 would produce this error